# Can't save list into Database using Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

This is a simple example for the problem i'm having in saving lists into my database.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InsertResultsIntoDatabase()
    {


        using (var context = new ResultContext())
        {
            DatabaseTestResults dbTestResults = new DatabaseTestResults();

            dbTestResults.ZipFileName = "report-nominal - Copy.zip";

            dbTestResults.testList.Add(1);
            context.DbTestResults.Add(dbTestResults);
            context.SaveChanges();


        }
```

in this point the debugger will show that context contains the `testList` and the `zipFileName` correctly.

```
        using (var context = new ResultContext())
        { 

            var query = context.DbTestResults.Find("report-nominal -            
                         Copy.zip");
         }
```

when trying to get the information from the database it's saved only `zipFileName` and the list is empty.
How do I save lists into database?

Comment: Is ZipFileName the primary key for DatabaseTestResults? Find expects a primary key value.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `context.Entry(dbTestResults).State = EntityState.Added` before `SaveChanges()`
Like this:

```
using (var context = new ResultContext())
{
     DatabaseTestResults dbTestResults = new DatabaseTestResults();

     dbTestResults.ZipFileName = "report-nominal - Copy.zip";

     context.DbTestResults.Add(dbTestResults);
     context.Entry(dbTestResults).State = EntityState.Added
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```